# Symfony how to converte object of class to double and check variables

Tags: php, symfony

I have the next code at symfony2 . When I try check variables in `public function subtractCredits` I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Object of class dorent\RentalBundle\Entity\Credit could not be converted to double

**My code:**

```
$credit->setAmount($creditsTotal - $credit->getAmount());
        if ($credit <= $creditsTotal) {
            if ($this->saveCredit($credit)) {
                //send credit subtracted notification email.
                if (array_key_exists('emailCreditsSubtracted', $credit->getServiceProvider()->getSettings())) {

<?php

namespace dorent\RentalBundle\Credit;

use dorent\RentalBundle\Entity\Credit;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use dorent\BaseBundle\Email\Email;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;

class CreditManager
{
    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager
    */
    protected $em;
    protected $email;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Email $email, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getNewCredit($serviceProvider, $customer, $user) {
        $credit = new Credit();
        $credit->setServiceProvider($serviceProvider);
        $credit->setCustomer($customer);
        $credit->setCreatedBy($user);
        return $credit;
    }

    public function getNewGiftCard($serviceProvider, $customer, $user) {
        $credit = new Credit();
        $credit->setServiceProvider($serviceProvider);
        $credit->setCustomer($customer);
        $credit->setCreatedBy($user);

        $credit->setAmount($this->getTotalAmountByCustomerAndServiceProvider($customer, $serviceProvider));

        $category = $this->em->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory')
            ->findOneByCode('GIFT-CARD');

        $credit->setCategory($category);

        return $credit;
    }

    public function saveCredit($credit) {

            $this->em->persist($credit);
            $this->em->flush();
            return true;
        }

    public function createCredit($payment) {
        $offer = $payment->getRental()->getOffer();
        $rental = $payment->getRental();

        $category = $this->em->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory')
            ->findOneByCode('REFUND');

        $credit = new Credit();
        $credit->setAmount($offer->getPrice());
        $credit->setCustomer($offer->getCustomer());
        $credit->setServiceProvider($offer->getServiceProvider());
        $credit->setCategory($category);

        $credit->setRental($rental);
        $rental->setCredit($credit);

        $this->em->persist($credit);
        $this->em->flush();
        return true;
    }

    public function getTotalAmountByCustomerAndServiceProvider($customer, $sp) {
        $credits = $this->em->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:Credit')
            ->findByCustomerAndServiceProvider($customer, $sp);

        return $this->getTotalAmount($credits);
    }

    public function getTotalAmount($credits) {
        $t = 0;

        foreach ($credits as $c) {
            $t += $c->getAmount();
        }

        return round($t, 2);
    }

    public function equals(CreditManager $object, $credit) {
        return $this->getTotalAmount($credit) == $object->getTotalAmount($credit);
    }

    public function subtractCredits($credit)
    {
        //here I get error
        $creditsTotal = $this->getTotalAmount($credit);

        $credit->setAmount($creditsTotal - $credit->getAmount());

        if ($credit <= $creditsTotal) {
            if ($this->saveCredit($credit)) {
                //send credit subtracted notification email.
                if (array_key_exists('emailCreditsSubtracted', $credit->getServiceProvider()->getSettings())) {
                    $this->email->sendCreditsSubtracted($credit);
                }
                return true;
            } else {

            }

            return false;
        }
    }


        //$credit->setAmount($credit->getAmount() * -1);

    public function calculateCreditExpiration() {
        $sps = $this->em->getRepository('dorentServiceProviderBundle:serviceProvider')->findAll();

        foreach ($sps as $key => $sp) {
            $validityPeriod = 0;
            $settings = $sp->getSettings();
            if (isset($settings['creditValidityPeriodDays'])) {
                $validityPeriod = $settings['creditValidityPeriodDays'];
            }
            $notificationPeriod = 0;
            if (isset($settings['creditExpirationNotificationDays'])) {
                $notificationPeriod = $settings['creditExpirationNotificationDays'];
            }

            if ($validityPeriod === 0) {
                $this->logger->info($sp->getName().": validity period not set");
                continue;
            } else {
                $this->logger->info($sp->getName().": validity period ".$validityPeriod);
                $this->calculateServiceProvider($sp, $validityPeriod, $notificationPeriod);
            }


        }
        $this->logger->info('End calculation');
    }

    private function expire($amount, $customer, $serviceProvider) {
        $msg = "EXPIRE: ".date_create()->format('Y-m-d')." ".$amount." ".$serviceProvider->getCode()." ".$customer->getId()." ".$customer->getName()."\n";
        $this->logger->info($msg);

        $category = $this->em->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory')
            ->findOneByCode('EXPIRED');
        $c = $this->getNewCredit($serviceProvider, $customer, null);
        $c->setAmount($amount * -1);
        $c->setCategory($category);
        $this->saveCredit($c);
    }

    private function notifyExpiresSoon($amount, $customer, $serviceProvider, $date) {
        $msg = "EXPIRES SOON: ".$date->format('Y-m-d')." ".$amount." ".$serviceProvider->getCode()." ".$customer->getId()." ".$customer->getName()."\n";
        $this->logger->info($msg);

        $this->email->notifyExpiresSoon($amount, $customer, $serviceProvider, $date);
    }

    private function calculateServiceProvider($sp, $validityPeriod, $notificationPeriod) {
        $this->logger->info('SP '.$sp->getCode());

        //calculate expiring now
        $date = date_create();
        date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($validityPeriod.' days'));

        $customers = $this->em->getRepository('dorentCustomerBundle:Customer')->findByServiceProvider($sp);

        foreach($customers as $key => $customer) {
            if ($this->getTotalAmountByCustomerAndServiceProvider($customer, $sp) <= 0) {
                // customer has zero credits
                continue;
            }

            $exp = $this->calculateCustomer($customer, $sp, $date, 0);
            if ($exp > 0) {
                //ADD EXPIRED CREDIT
                $this->expire($exp, $customer, $sp);
            }

            //notification
            if ($notificationPeriod !== 0) {
                $this->calculateNotification($customer, $sp, $validityPeriod, $notificationPeriod);
            }


        }
    }

    private function calculateNotification($customer, $sp, $validityPeriod, $notificationPeriod) {
        $lookAhead = 0;
        $exp = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $notificationPeriod; $i++) {
            $date = date_create();
            date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($i.' days'));

            $expDate = clone $date;

            date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($validityPeriod.' days'));
            $exp = $this->calculateCustomer($customer, $sp, $date, $lookAhead);

            if ($exp > 0) {
                $lookAhead += $exp * -1;
            }
        }
        if ($exp > 0) {
            $this->notifyExpiresSoon($exp, $customer, $sp, $expDate);
        }
    }

    private function calculateCustomer($customer, $serviceProvider, $date, $lookAhead = 0) {
        $cr = $this->em->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:Credit');
        $credits = $cr->findByCustomerAndServiceProviderAfterDate($customer, $serviceProvider, $date);

        if (count($credits) === 0) { return 0; }

        //sum of credits created < date, if <= 0 return, e.g. 100 + 200 = 300
        $sumOfOldCredits = $cr->sumByCustomerAndServiceProviderBeforeDate($customer, $serviceProvider, $date);

        if ($sumOfOldCredits === null) {
            $sumOfOldCredits = 0;
        }

        if ($sumOfOldCredits <= 0) { return 0; }

        //sum of used credits > date, e.g. -200
        $sumOfUsedCredits = $cr->sumOfUsedCredits($customer, $serviceProvider, $date);
        if ($sumOfUsedCredits === null) {
            $sumOfUsedCredits = 0;
        }

        //credits to expire now = 300 + (-200) = 100 credits, if sum < 0 no credits expire
        $expiring = $sumOfOldCredits + $sumOfUsedCredits + $lookAhead;

        return $expiring;
    }

}
```

This is method didn't work.

```
public function getTotalAmount($credits)
    {
        if (!is_array($credits)) $credits = array($credits);

        $t = 0;

        foreach ($credits as $c) {
            $t += $c->getAmount();
        }

        return round($t, 2);
    }


    public function subtractCredits($credit)
    {
        $creditsTotal = $this->getTotalAmount($credit);
        if ($credit->getAmount() < $creditsTotal) {
            $creditsTotal = $this->getTotalAmount($credit);
            $credit->setAmount($creditsTotal - $credit->getAmount());
            if ($this->saveCredit($credit)) {
                //send credit subtracted notification email.
                if (array_key_exists('emailCreditsSubtracted', $credit->getServiceProvider()->getSettings())) {
                    $this->email->sendCreditsSubtracted($credit);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

CreditsController:

```
<?php

namespace dorent\ServiceDeskBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range;

class CreditsController extends ServiceDeskBaseController
{

    private function getForm($credit) {
        return $this->createFormBuilder($credit)
                   ->add('amount', 'number',
                    ['label' => 'credit.labels.amount',
                     'constraints' => new Range(array('min' => 0, 'minMessage' => 'credit.amount.min')),
                    ])
                   ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                        'label' => 'credit.labels.category',
                        'class' => 'dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory',
                        'property' => 'description'))
                   ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                        'label' => 'credit.labels.description',
                        'required' => false))
                   ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'credit.labels.save'])
                   ->getForm();
    }

    public function addAction(Request $request, $provider, $customerId)
    {
        $sp = $this->getProvider($provider);
        $customer = $this->getCustomer($customerId, $sp);
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $creditManager = $this->get('credit_manager');

        $credit = $creditManager->getNewCredit($sp, $customer, $user);

        $form = $this->getForm($credit);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            if ($creditManager->saveCredit($credit)) {
                $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.created');
            } else {
                $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.create_failed');
            }

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
               'notice',
               $message
            );

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('service_desk_customer', array(
                'provider' => $sp->getCode(),
                'customerId' => $customerId
                )
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('dorentServiceDeskBundle:Credits:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'provider' => $sp,
            'customer' => $customer,
        ));
    }

    public function subtractAction(Request $request, $provider, $customerId)
    {


        $sp = $this->getProvider($provider);
        $customer = $this->getCustomer($customerId, $sp);
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $creditManager = $this->get('credit_manager');

        $credit = $creditManager->getNewCredit($sp, $customer, $user);

        $form = $this->getForm($credit);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ($creditManager->subtractCredits($credit)) {
                $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.created');
            } else {
                $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.create_failed');
            }

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
               'notice',
               $message
            );

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('service_desk_customer', array(
                'provider' => $sp->getCode(),
                'customerId' => $customerId
                )
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('dorentServiceDeskBundle:Credits:subtract.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'provider' => $sp,
            'customer' => $customer,
        ));
    }

    public function giftAction(Request $request, $provider, $customerId)
    {
        $sp = $this->getProvider($provider);
        $customer = $this->getCustomer($customerId, $sp);
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $creditManager = $this->get('credit_manager');

        $credit = $creditManager->getNewGiftCard($sp, $customer, $user);

        $form = $this->getForm($credit);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory')
                ->findOneByCode('GIFT-CARD');

            $credit->setCategory($category);

            if ($credit->getAmount() > $creditManager->getTotalAmountByCustomerAndServiceProvider($customer, $sp)) {
                $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.create_failed');
            } else {

                if ($creditManager->subtractCredits($credit)) {
                    $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.created');
                    $this->get('session')->set('gift-card-created', $credit->getId());
                } else {
                    $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('credit.message.create_failed');
                }
            }

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
               'notice',
               $message
            );

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('service_desk_customer', array(
                'provider' => $sp->getCode(),
                'customerId' => $customerId
                )
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('dorentServiceDeskBundle:Credits:gift.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'provider' => $sp,
            'customer' => $customer,
        ));

    }

    public function printGiftCardAction(Request $request, $provider, $creditId) {
        $sp = $this->getProvider($provider);

        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:CreditCategory')
            ->findOneByCode('GIFT-CARD');

        $credit = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('dorentRentalBundle:Credit')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'category' => $category,
                'serviceProvider' => $sp,
                'id' => $creditId
            ))
        ;

        if ($credit === null) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('The credit does not exist');
        }

        // NOT USED FOR NOW
        // $validityPeriod = 12;
        // $expirationDate = date_create();
        // date_add($expirationDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string($validityPeriod.' months'));

        return $this->render('dorentServiceDeskBundle:Credits:gift-card.html.twig', array(
            'provider' => $sp,
            'credit' => $credit,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: check this line: if ($credit <= $creditsTotal)

Comment: Don't you need if to be `if ($credit->getAmount() < $creditsTotal)` instead? Although it does look like a weird set of calculations, the only way that would fail is it the original credit amount was `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//here I get error
$creditsTotal = $this->getTotalAmount($credit);
```

1. You need to put array of Credit objects as argument of **getTotalAmount** or
   You can change your method like that:

   ```
   public function getTotalAmount($credits) {
       if(!is_array($credits)) $credits = array($credits);

       $t = 0;

       foreach ($credits as $c) {
           $t += $c->getAmount();
       }

       return round($t, 2);
   }
   ```
2. You cannot doing something like that: `if ($credit <= $creditsTotal)` because $credit is an object of class Credit. You should use some method from $credit like `$credit->getAmount()` or whatever you want to compare with $creditsTotal.

Comment: I try your code but code didn't work. I touch code upper. Could you check my code?

Comment: Ok. But please tell me why it shouldn't save a new credit? Because i don't know the logic of your application. I  guess that you need to change `if ($credit->getAmount() < $creditsTotal)` to `if ($creditsTotal > 0)`.

Comment: For example if $totalCredits = 90;  $credit->getAmount() = 40 code should save  $totalCredits - $credit->getAmount() = 90 - 40 = 50. I just wanna don't save the negative numbers for example 40 - 50 = - 10.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense because in your situation you have one object of class $credit and `$this->getTotalAmount($credit)` always will be equal to `$credit->getAmount()`

Comment: What I should do in this situation?

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve by using the method `subtractCredits($credit)`. Please tell me when and where do you using it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101765/discussion-between-rider-by-and-koovvall).